# Вывод сообщения с задержкой в С

Tags: c

Я только начал изучать С,и у меня возник вопрос,как мне вывести какое-либо сообщение(к примеру тот же Helo world) с определенной задержкой по времени(например 5 секунд)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На C и C++98 нет платформенно независимого способа это сделать, придется использовать средства платформы:

Если дело происходит под Windows:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     Sleep(5*1000); // 5000 миллисекунд = 5 секунд
     printf("Hello World!\n");
     return 0;
}
```

Под Linux:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     usleep(5*1000000); // 5000000 микросекунд = 5 секунд
     printf("Hello World!\n");
     return 0;
}
```